# Combining two worksheet functions into one code

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code within a worksheet (using a private sub) and I want to divide two numbers. Is there a way to use this code?

```
Can.Range("AB4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quotient(.Max(Price, POS))
```

Thanks,

Griffin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to divide `price` by `pos`, just use:

```
Can.Range("AB4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Price, pos)
```

as you probably know, Quotient *"Returns the integer portion of a division."*

if you want to return the result of the division then use:

```
Can.Range("AB4") = Price/pos
```

Comment: please use `Can.Range("AB4").Value` to set a value and not rely on defaults. This will make it clear if value, function or formatting is set, or if the range itself is being referenced.

Comment: @ja72, well the context makes everything clear here. Anyhow explicit default parameter never harms. Out of curiosity does such a suggestion apply to answers from "under 10k" only?

Comment: I wish I could have given everyone the check. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

To divide maximum price by pos,

```
with Application.WorksheetFunction
    Can.Range("AB4") = .Quotient(.Max(Price), POS)
end with
```

Comment: The code works but the only problem is that the quotient value is rounded down. The value I want is 67.74 but this is returning 67. When I add more decimals, the value is 67.00. Why is this?

Comment: The value is 67. How do I raise the number of decimals?

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. I dont know if this means anything but this is a private sub and both Price and POS are declared as Long. I tried declaring them as Double but it did not do anything

Comment: From [QUOTIENT FUNCTION](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUOTIENT-function-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee) *Tip: If you want to divide numeric values, you should use the "/" operator as there isn't a DIVIDE function in Excel. For example, to divide 5 by 2, you would type =5/2 into a cell, which returns 2.5. The QUOTIENT function for these same numbers =QUOTIENT(5,2) returns 2, since QUOTIENT doesn't return a remainder.*